# PDF how to get height of text

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, text, height

I'm using PDF2JSON a module for node, it returns an array of Text with x, y and w properties, but no height.

How can I accurately determine the height of the text?  I've tried using the fontSize but this doesn't look correct as in cases where the text is at the bottom of the page the y + fontSize gives a result outside of the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To work out the font size in mm using the 'FontSize' field, do the following:

FontSize is specified in units of 1/72 of an inch, so to convert this to mm, 
multiply (1/72) * 25.4

I have verified this by printing capital A's on a sheet of A4 from size 8 to size 72, as the font gets closer to 72 you also have to allow for the bits you cannot see, hence the coloured background.

Then its just a case of calling pointToPixel, this is a method in the pdfunit.js file (lib of pdf2json) which converts inches to pixels...use the value from the inches column.

[image]